# Weil Pairing on Linear Algebraic Groups

Tags: algebraic-groups

I've been studying the Weil pairing on elliptic curves recently and discovered that it has a generalisation to an abelian variety $A$ with its dual $A^{\vee}$, which then becomes a pairing on an elliptic curve as this is isomorphic to its dual.

Is there a similar construction for the Weil pairing for linear algebraic groups, or something that has similar properties to it?